# NSUrlConnection When Lock the Screen?

Tags: ios, background, nsurlconnection

I have tried some ways to perform NSURLConnection when lock the screen but none of it works.

I have tried as following:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startConnection) withObject:nil];
```

I also tried:

```
dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.download", NULL);
dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{
  [self startConnection];
});
```

in startConnection:

```
- (void)startConnection{
  ... some URL processing

  responseData_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  connection_ =
  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}
```

The NSURLConnection delegate methods aren't called by this way.
What is the real code to make it works? Thanks!

**A small update that may help**:

It only calls this delegate method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

with message:

> A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

I am very sure my wi-fi is connected, still not sure why it is called :(

Comment: What do you mean by "sleep mode"?

Comment: when I lock the screen.. I will edit my post, it seems ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lock your screen, your app will be turn into background mode, **not background running mode.**
If you want to download while user locks the screen, you should check this method [UIApplication -beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]

Comment: Here is an example demonstrating how to use it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258408/lock-screen-interrupts-nsurlconnection#13263029

Comment: @CarmeloS, Is there way to determine if my app run in "background mode" or in "background running mode"? I have the same issue and I want to pause my connection.