# NSURLConnection stops when screen locks

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am working on the app where video is uploading to Facebook. It is working fine till the app is active and also If it goes to background. For background I used following lines of code to not interrupt the connection.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

   self.backgroundTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
        self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
   }
```

But if user locks the screen by pressing on/off button the NSURLConnection get stops. Is there any other way to make the nsurlconnection active even on the locked screen. Please suggest me some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lock screen interrupts NSURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258408/lock-screen-interrupts-nsurlconnection)

Comment: @Sam how it works when screen locks/unlocks